# Date Picker in Laravel Collectives

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5

How to implement a data picker in Laravel Collectives? I have the following at the moment but need to manually type the date.

```
{{Form::date('name', \Carbon\Carbon::now())}}
```

Comment: Date pickers are an entirely front-end implementation. You’ll be better off asking this question as an HTML and JavaScript related question, or just finding one.

Answer (score 0):

for date format should be 'Y-m-d':

you can try:

```
{{Form::date('name', date('Y-m-d'))}}
```

or using carbon

```
{{Form::date('name', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'))}}
```